# 'Add to Reading List' share menu item doesn't work in Mojave

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, macos-mojave

The following code doesn't work anymore in Mojave:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://apple.com"),
    let listService = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingService.Name.addToSafariReadingList),
    listService.canPerform(withItems: [url])
{
    listService.perform(withItems: [url])
}
```

The code is executed without any errors within the app, but nothing is being added to the Safari reading list.

A lot of non-Apple apps that offer a 'Add to Reading List' share menu item, suffer from the same problem: nothing new appears in the Safari reading list.

In the Console I saw a few errors indicating it is related to AppleEvent sandboxing, introduced in Mojave. So I added a `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` item with a description to the Info.plist, but without any success.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As a temporarily workaround, until this 'issue' is fixed by Apple, you can use the following code:

```
if #available(macOS 10.14, *) { // Don't use the workaround on earlier macOS versions
    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.init(name: .general)
    pasteboard.clearContents()
    pasteboard.setString(url.absoluteString, forType: .string)
    NSPerformService("Add to Reading List", pasteboard)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probleem seems to be fixed in macOS 10.14.4